# Update multiple columns of a table in SQL Server using R

Tags: sql, r, for-loop, sql-update, rodbc

This is `table1` in SQL Server:

```
Last   Country   colA   colB   colC
------------------------------------
1      ARG       NA     NA     NA
2      NULL      NA     NA     NA
3      CAM       NA     NA     NA
4      NULL      NA     NA     NA
5      NULL      NA     NA     NA
```

This is my dataframe `DF` in R:

```
colA   colB   colc
20     foo    1.2
12     bar    12.2
1      tam    10.3
15     red    0.8
```

Now how do I iterate for every row in `DF` so that it could be updated in `table1`?

This is the code in r

```
conn <- odbcDriverConnect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=dusty;DATABASE=Area;UID=admin;PWD=abcd@123;autocommit=True')
data <- sqlQuery(conn,paste("select * from table1;"))
for(i in 1:length(DF)) {
update.query <- paste("UPDATE table1 ", 
                       "SET colA=?",
                       "SET colB=?",
                       "SET colC=?",
                       "WHERE Country is NULL", sep="")
dummy <- sqlQuery(conn, update.query)
}
```

Any suggestions how it could be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should do it for you.

```
library(RODBC)

connHandle <- odbcConnect("cakesDatabase")
newData <- read.csv("newData.csv", stringsAsFactors = F)

for(row in 1:nrow(newData)){
  query <- paste0(
    "UPDATE cakes 
     SET price = ", newData$price[row], " 
     WHERE cake = '", newData$cake[row], "'"
  )
  sqlQuery(connHandle, query)
}

odbcClose(connHandle)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library("RODBC")

connection <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};
                            server=server_name;
                            database=db_name;
                            trusted_connection=true')

column1 <- 6
column2 <-999
column3 <- 999
column4 <- 44
column5 <- -128

#update data
update_data <- paste0("UPDATE TABLE 
                  SET column2 = ",column2,", column3 = ",column3," , column4 = 
",column4,", column5 = ",column5,"  
                  where column1= ",column1,"")
#execute updata data
update_recorddf<-sqlQuery(connection,update_data) 

odbcClose(connection)
```